# How to switch between nautilus window and (gnome-)terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, nautilus, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I need a fast possibility to switch between a nautilus window and a (gnome-terminal) in the same working directory.

At the moment I'm using the following setup:

**nautilus -> terminal**: nautilus-open-terminal (rightclick > open terminal here) & close nautilus window manually

**terminal -> nautilus**: alias explorer="nautilus $(pwd) && exit"

My problem is, that on the one hand [nautilus -> terminal] takes some time (rightclick..manual close..): I'd like to have a hotkey or something more direct for this operation. And on the other hand [terminal -> nautilus] does only work when there is already a nautilus instance running somewhere, otherwise the terminal blocks running nautilus and doesn't close itself.

As I'm using a tiling window manager (XMonad) I don't want both windows to be running at the same time.

Any Ideas?